# How to handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException in global exception handler in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I'm uploading multi-part file data in one of my REST service and I have defined a file size limit in application.properties using "spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB" attribute. I have a global exception handler class where I want to handler this exception and show user a custom message but my global exception handler unable to catch the exception.

**Global Exception handler**:

```
@ControllerAdvice("storageservice.resource")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException maxUploadSizeExceededException,
                                                                       WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Inside handle max file upload size..");
        return buildErrorResponse(maxUploadSizeExceededException, HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE);
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 10485760 bytes.
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at asr.logging.http.servlet.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilter(AsrLoggingFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 10485760 bytes.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2939)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2797)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 10485760 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileItemStreamImpl.java:114)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2895)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The exception handler will never be invoked because it never reaches a controller/handler. You could use a servlet Filter to achieve the same. One thing that might also help is to set the `spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily` to `true` instead of the default `false`. That will delay the exception (I suspect) leading to your handler being mapped and your exception handler working.

Comment: @M.Deinum it worked. Just one question, if I'll enable this property to handle the exception in my controller then is it going to be a performance problem?? What I believe in case of resolve lazily = true all the file content downloaded into server before rasing the exception. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The content will  be downloaded either way, only it is either at mapping time or at the point where you are injecting or using the `MultipartFile` parts.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @M. Deinum, by default Spring sets "spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily = false", so the exception never comes to the global exception handler. In order to handle the exception at the global exception handler, we need to set the property as true.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=true
```